# Why am I getting error when calling realloc on a char[]?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, realloc

I have char[] as such

```
char string[] = "Hello world !!!";
```

when I'm trying to reallocate it's memory I'm getting error

```
realloc(string, 50); // error here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only `realloc` things you `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`'ed. A `char` array is not any of those things, so it is normal for you to get an error in this case.

Answer (score 3):

> Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc()

You have violated the Standard, so you are rewarded with Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
realloc(string, 50);
```

argument to `realloc()` , i.e. `string` should be got via `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` if not null